# (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field `'crvData'`, but its type

`(CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer)`

is not compatible with the type of

`control (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer)`.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having issues as above please check your crystal reports dll reference.

you have to add same reference for control. Compatibility error occur if you are using control of version 10.5.3700.0 and you have added reference of 13.0.2000.0. then you will be receiving above error.

This is also possible if you have installed SAP Crystal reports along with Visual studio 2008.

Visual Studio 2008 has crystal report version 10.5.3700.0